# HttpWebRequest automatically adding IfNoneMatch header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a RESTful service. I've implemented E-Tags, modified dates and cache control headers in my service.

I am also writing a very simple Get, Put, Post, Delete request/response API for our scripting guys to use.

I'm using HttpWebRequest, which I thought was a low-level class with fine control, so I've added APIs for supplying ETags and conditional Gets etc. etc.

The thing is, HttpWebRequest seems to be doing it all itself!! When I set the cache level to Revalidate, it seems to work with the WinInet cache (on Windows 7 desktop) and automatically tack on the if-none-match header with the cached ETag value.

Superficially, you'd think that this was cool; no need to do your own caching of ETags and representations, but then its not the truth.

For example, my web service returns a NotModified response to a conditional get, but the response that ends up coming into my client is 200 OK, so my tests need to account for this abstraction.

Does anyone know more about this undocumented behavior?

Luke

Comment: It's not explicitly documented, but somewhat implied by the fact you're using Revalidate. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cache.httprequestcachelevel(v=vs.100).aspx details the different levels further. `Revalidate` indicates that winnet will ask the server whether the cached response has changed and if not it will serve the previously stored representation. In your case that'll be a 200 with the cached representation. Beware though - I've seen situations where the 304 is returned and the cached representation is a 500! Ick!

Comment: You might wanna look at my work on cachingHandler part of https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib and more detail on my blog http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/aspnet-web-api-caching-handler.html

Comment: @Dean - thanks - I've always assumed that the Revalidate indicates my intent to any caches out on the web, not to .NET/Windows.

Comment: @Aliostad - interesting what you've done there, I'll bookmark that for later.